# How to make a printable file for a mobile application using python tkinter?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, printing

I am working on a personal project just to automate some manual work in the office.

Here I have to print a Receipt(Challan Form) with some data in it as an output.
I am not sure which file format should I use to print the output.
I am going to use this application on an android device so the choices seem very little. If I were using the desktop system then I had plenty of the choices like (.xlsx, .pdf, .docx) but I don't know how to accomplish this task for an android device.

[image]

**Workflow:**

1. User will enter some data in the text boxes, e.g Fee, Date, Name.
2. Then Press the Print Button and Output will be printed out with the
   text box data from the printer via Wi-fi connection.

My question is how to make this receipt/file in an android system using python(Tkinter). Please suggest some sort of article or link.